# xlsxwriter: Is it possible to open and see the Workbook before the close method?

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

In order to debug and calibrate different things, I would like to open the workbook at the beginning of the process i.e.

```
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook()
```

I also tried with the with statement:

```
with xlsxwriter.Workbook() as wb:
```

But I didn't find anything which allow me to open the excel-sheet before the close method. I am pretty sure that there is an option for that.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to open and see the Workbook before the close method?

No. The file isn't created until you call close (either explicitly with `close()` or implicitly when using `with`).